# How to Discard entire folder using SourceTree

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

How can we discard entire folder Using SourceTree ?
(I am willing to discard / revert all the changes in a particular folder including all the files in that folder )

I found many solutions using command line!

So is there any such way to do using SourceTree UI ?

I am using

- Atlassian Source Tree - V 1.8..
- GIT HUB

Thanks

Comment: SourceTree will allow you to run commands from the terminal - just click the Terminal button in the top-right.  That tends to be easier than using the GUI for advanced commands.

Answer (score 1):

Click File status in WORKSPACE, select files that you'd like to discard, then click three dots on the right, you will see discard file.